# jQuery - Show total divs of selected persons

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

i am new with jQuery. I am trying to make the follow thing happen but it still don't want to work :( I hope that someone can help me with my issue.
So i have already typed some codes, but i think there is still something wrong.

So if the total persons are 4, i want that 4 extra divs will be showed on the form

You can check the code on : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5tj1sec6/4)

```
<div> 
    <select name="persons" onchange="ShowTotalPerson();ShowDivs();" id="num-people">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div> <select name="kids" onchange="ShowTotalPerson();ShowDivs();" id="num-kids">
<option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option></select>
    </div>

    <div> 
       <select name="babys" onchange="ShowTotalPerson();ShowDivs();" id="num-babys">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
       </select>
    </div>

<div >Total Persons:
                        <span id="person-total">0</span>
                    </div>

<div class="ShowFirst1" >hello</div>

 <script>
       $(function() {

         $('.ShowFirst1').hide();

       });</script>
```

### and the js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', 'div select',function(){
        var sum = 0;
       $('div select').each(function(){
           var thisVal = parseInt($(this).val());
           sum += thisVal;
       });
        $('#person-total').text(sum);
    });
});



function ShowDivs() {

 var totalPersons = (($('#num-people').val() == '1'))

 if (spainoctdate)
     $(".ShowFirst1").show();
 else
     $(".ShowFirst1").hide();


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

by this way you can get sum of person

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'div select',function(){
        var sum = 0;
       $('div select').each(function(){
           var thisVal = parseInt($(this).val());
           sum += thisVal;
       });
        $('#person-total').text(sum);
    });
 });
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5tj1sec6/2/)

THEN you can use sum in for loop to add extra Divs

Comment: Thanks! But can i also do if #person-total that value add that amount of extra divs?

Comment: Like If the total person amount is: 4 then 4 times this div will appear:  <div class="ShowFirst1" style="display:none" >hello 1</div>

Comment: I want to append it to the body yes, so if the total person is 4, there will be automatically added 4 divs, if they change to 0 persons then the div has to dissapear. Thanks for you help

Comment: thanks for you help, but you don't understand me i think. i'm sorry. I Mean if the Total Person is 4, then there should be SHOWED 4 divs on the form, if total person is 3 then show 3 Divs -- So if the Total Person is 4 then show 4 divs like : <div name="first">Content</div>  and  <div name="second">Content</div>  and  <div name="third">Content</div>  and  <div name="four">Content</div> if they select 0 again, then hide all the div, if they select 20 person total, then show 20 divs @mohamed-yousef

Comment: Thanks! but what if i have some forms in the extra div like : <div class="passenger1"><label for="passenger_name">Passenger 1</label>
    <input name="passenger_name" type="text" id="passenger_name" placeholder="FIRSTNAME">
    and 
    <input name="passenger_lname" type="text" id="passenger_lname" placeholder="LASTNAME"> 
    and 
<input name="passenger_age" type="text" id="passenger_age" placeholder="AGE"></div> ?? How should i post the input values of each div then?

Comment: @MissesSalima don't use enter when use .append()  html should be one line http://jsfiddle.net/5tj1sec6/11/

Comment: Oh okay i see thanks.. But now i have a last problem.. I need different input NAMES like for first passenger name="passenger1" and for second passenger name="passenger2" because it will be sended as a form so i need that they will get automaticly name values for the input like "passenger1, passenger2, passenger3, passenger4, etc. Is that possible? Thank you very much for you help! May god bless you! @mohamed-yousef

Comment: I fixed it with : <input name="passenger_name'+i+'"> Thanks alot